# git grep--but restricted to new or modified files in the index

Tags: git, grep

Is it possible to get `git grep` to search only new or modified files in the index/cache?

(The use-case for this is to use in a pre-commit hook that looks for "debug" code such as `console.log` in the prospective commit.  But I'm not bothered by `console.log` in "existing" code.  Preferably this would also fail to match instances of `console.log` that are *removed*, but I can live with those matching!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out the way to do this is not via `git grep`, but by a completely different command, that also happens to be able to search: `git diff-index`. (Another triumph for simplicity and orthogonality...)

What I wanted can be achieved via:

```
$ git diff-index -U --cached -G <regexp> HEAD
```

Comment: Note: the search is restricted to the _changed lines_ in new or modified files. To search the entire contents of modified files, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592933/how-to-grep-search-in-modified-files-of-working-directory-which-are-not-yet-been

Comment: With --cached it shows only staged files. Without --cached it shows *both* staged and unstaged files. How do I show *only* unstaged files?

Answer (score 15):

I usually just do something like:

```
git diff | grep TODO
```

If you have enough changed lines to make that annoying, then I add `| grep '^+'`, or start messing around with `-[ABC]` options.

Comment: (well, usually `svn diff` or `hg diff`...)

Comment: Please read the question, your solution won't include newly created files

Answer (score 1):

I have a Perl program called `dirty` that detects new or changed files in a repo, and then I can just say `grep string_to_find $(dirty)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = qx/svn status 2>&1/;
exit if @lines == 0;

chomp @lines;
my $first = $lines[0];
if ( $first !~ /svn: warning: .+ not a working copy/ ) {
    @lines = grep { !/^[?]/ } @lines; # Ignore unversioned files
    s/^........// for @lines;
    print "$_\n" for @lines;
    exit;
}

@lines = qx/git status --short --untracked-files=no/;
chomp @lines;
s/^...// for @lines;

print "$_\n" for @lines;
```

Note that it is smart enough to check for dirty files in a Subversion repo or a Git repo, depending on which it detects.

Comment: This didn't completely work for me with `git`. It found the text I searched for in an existing changed file, but not in a newly created file in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a git pre-commit hook (it's just a shell script, marked as executable, in your .git/hooks directory) that scans your commit diff for any newly added lines (the ones with `+` symbol at the beginning for your "debug" pattern), and do an `exit 1` if it found such lines.

This tells `git commit` to abort the commit before starting your $EDITOR for editing the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is small aliases for grep'ing changed lines:

```
    grep-changed = "!f(){ git diff-index -U -G \"$@\" HEAD; };f "
    grep-staged  = "!f(){ git diff-index -U --cached -G \"$@\" HEAD; };f "
```