# How to grep search in modified files of working directory which are not yet been staged(indexed)?

Tags: git

It seems `git grep` doesn't have any option to search only in working directory modified files prior to indexing those files. is there any native git command for this purpose or should I use a combo git/linux commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

by using linux `grep` and `git ls-files`:

```bsh
$ grep -s "search pattern" $(git ls-files -m)
```

note 1: grep's `-s` option is provided for `Suppress  error  messages about nonexistent or unreadable files` because `git ls-files -m` lists deleted files too which causes `grep` give `"No such file or directory"` error when encounters a nonexistent file.

note 2: git ls-files' `-m` option is for listing only `modified` files(which also lists removed files too!)

Comment: This searches the entire contents of modified files. To search only the _changed lines_, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955390/git-grep-but-restricted-to-new-or-modified-files-in-the-index

Comment: for fish users:
grep -s "search pattern" (git ls-files -m)
Just omit the dollar!

Answer (score 0):

`git grep` is modelled on plain `grep`, perhaps you should just use that.

Comment: I prefer to use git build-in grep because of performance boost git-grep gives over grep, but if you know commands to get list of modified files and pass it to linux's grep I take that as an answer.

Comment: Look at `git ls-files --modified` and such

Comment: it seems you didn't see my answer which use your suggested "git ls-files" command.